Installing Ubuntu 24 server and creating bootable image for RPi4 from script
I am trying to make an automated script which would use latest Ubuntu 24 server image and create /boot and /root folders packed into *img.xz file.
I would also like to install and modify the /root folder with packages and folders/files I need for work (ROS, some tools etc.).
Basicly, what RPI IMAGER does, but a bit more customizable.
I am struggling with how and where to even begin, just to install Ubuntu image into a temporary folder, how to create bootable /boot folder with RPi boot files and so on.
Has anyone tried to do anything similar to that? Is it safe to do it on local machine or is it better to use remote machine (like a PC or RPi)?
Until now, I have tried to just dd the ubuntu.img I got from the web onto the SD card, but that seems to be very far away from what I'm trying to achieve.
Thanks for any information!

There is no version of Ubuntu just called 24 except Ubuntu Core. Is that what you are using?

Oh, sorry. It's ubuntu-24.04-live-server-amd64.

You can SSH into the raspberry pi to install whatever software you want to install, even if the Pi is not connected to a monitor https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/remote-access.html. Manually changing the image to install software is not so easy
